# ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] if (ser.find("Error")){

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I am trying to use Arduino IDE to detect temperature and pulse rate using LM35 sensor and pulse sensor.

This is the code:

```c++
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
float pulse = 0;
float temp = 0;
SoftwareSerial ser(9,10);
String apiKey = "MVLG8S8L6138FCR4";
 
// Variables
int pulsePin = A0; // Pulse Sensor purple wire connected to analog pin 0
int blinkPin = 7 ; // pin to blink led at each beat
int fadePin = 13; // pin to do fancy classy fading blink at each beat
int fadeRate = 0; // used to fade LED on with PWM on fadePin
 
// Volatile Variables, used in the interrupt service routine!
 
volatile int BPM; // int that holds raw Analog in 0. updated every 2mS
volatile int Signal; // holds the incoming raw data
volatile int IBI = 600; // int that holds the time interval between beats! Must be seeded!
volatile boolean Pulse = false; // "True" when User's live heartbeat is detected. "False" when nota "live beat".
volatile boolean QS = false; // becomes true when Arduoino finds a beat.
 
// Regards Serial OutPut -- Set This Up to your needs
static boolean serialVisual = true; // Set to 'false' by Default. Re-set to 'true' to see Arduino Serial Monitor ASCII Visual Pulse
volatile int rate[10]; // array to hold last ten IBI values
volatile unsigned long sampleCounter = 0; // used to determine pulse timing
volatile unsigned long lastBeatTime = 0; // used to find IBI
volatile int P = 512; // used to find peak in pulse wave, seeded
volatile int T = 512; // used to find trough in pulse wave, seeded
volatile int thresh = 525; // used to find instant moment of heart beat, seeded
volatile int amp = 100; // used to hold amplitude of pulse waveform, seeded
volatile boolean firstBeat = true; // used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM
volatile boolean secondBeat = false; // used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM
 
void setup()
{
lcd.begin(16, 2);
pinMode(blinkPin,OUTPUT); // pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
pinMode(fadePin,OUTPUT); // pin that will fade to your heartbeat!
Serial.begin(115200); // we agree to talk fast!
interruptSetup(); // sets up to read Pulse Sensor signal every 2mS
 
// IF YOU ARE POWERING The Pulse Sensor AT VOLTAGE LESS THAN THE BOARD VOLTAGE,
 
// UN-COMMENT THE NEXT LINE AND APPLY THAT VOLTAGE TO THE A-REF PIN
 
// analogReference(EXTERNAL);
 
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print(" Patient Health");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print(" Monitoring ");
delay(4000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Initializing....");
delay(5000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Getting Data....");
ser.begin(9600);
ser.println("AT");
delay(1000);
ser.println("AT+GMR");
delay(1000);
ser.println("AT+CWMODE=3");
delay(1000);
ser.println("AT+RST");
delay(5000);
ser.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
delay(1000);
 
String cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"Alexahome\",\"98765432\"";
ser.println(cmd);
delay(1000);
ser.println("AT+CIFSR");
delay(1000);
}
 
// Where the Magic Happens
void loop()
{
serialOutput();
if (QS == true) // A Heartbeat Was Found
{
 
// BPM and IBI have been Determined
// Quantified Self "QS" true when arduino finds a heartbeat
fadeRate = 255; // Makes the LED Fade Effect Happen, Set 'fadeRate' Variable to 255 to fade LED with pulse
serialOutputWhenBeatHappens(); // A Beat Happened, Output that to serial.
QS = false; // reset the Quantified Self flag for next time
}
ledFadeToBeat(); // Makes the LED Fade Effect Happen
delay(20); // take a break
read_temp();
esp_8266();
}
void ledFadeToBeat()
{
fadeRate -= 15; // set LED fade value
fadeRate = constrain(fadeRate,0,255); // keep LED fade value from going into negative numbers!
analogWrite(fadePin,fadeRate); // fade LED
}
void interruptSetup()
{
// Initializes Timer2 to throw an interrupt every 2mS.
TCCR2A = 0x02; // DISABLE PWM ON DIGITAL PINS 3 AND 11, AND GO INTO CTC MODE
TCCR2B = 0x06; // DON'T FORCE COMPARE, 256 PRESCALER
OCR2A = 0X7C; // SET THE TOP OF THE COUNT TO 124 FOR 500Hz SAMPLE RATE
TIMSK2 = 0x02; // ENABLE INTERRUPT ON MATCH BETWEEN TIMER2 AND OCR2A
sei(); // MAKE SURE GLOBAL INTERRUPTS ARE ENABLED
}
void serialOutput()
{ // Decide How To Output Serial.
if (serialVisual == true)
{
arduinoSerialMonitorVisual('-', Signal); // goes to function that makes Serial Monitor Visualizer
}
else
{
sendDataToSerial('S', Signal); // goes to sendDataToSerial function
}
}
void serialOutputWhenBeatHappens()
{
if (serialVisual == true) // Code to Make the Serial Monitor Visualizer Work
{
Serial.print("*** Heart-Beat Happened *** "); //ASCII Art Madness
Serial.print("BPM: ");
Serial.println(BPM);
}
else
{
sendDataToSerial('B',BPM); // send heart rate with a 'B' prefix
sendDataToSerial('Q',IBI); // send time between beats with a 'Q' prefix
}
}
void arduinoSerialMonitorVisual(char symbol, int data )
{
const int sensorMin = 0; // sensor minimum, discovered through experiment
const int sensorMax = 1024; // sensor maximum, discovered through experiment
int sensorReading = data; // map the sensor range to a range of 12 options:
int range = map(sensorReading, sensorMin, sensorMax, 0, 11);
// do something different depending on the
// range value:
switch (range)
{
case 0:
Serial.println(""); /////ASCII Art Madness
break;
case 1:
Serial.println("---");
break;
case 2:
Serial.println("------");
break;
case 3:
Serial.println("---------");
break;
case 4:
Serial.println("------------");
break;
case 5:
Serial.println("--------------|-");
break;
case 6:
Serial.println("--------------|---");
break;
case 7:
Serial.println("--------------|-------");
break;
case 8:
Serial.println("--------------|----------");
break;
case 9:
Serial.println("--------------|----------------");
break;
case 10:
Serial.println("--------------|-------------------");
break;
case 11:
Serial.println("--------------|-----------------------");
break;
}
}
 
void sendDataToSerial(char symbol, int data )
{
Serial.print(symbol);
Serial.println(data);
}
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) //triggered when Timer2 counts to 124
{
cli(); // disable interrupts while we do this
Signal = analogRead(pulsePin); // read the Pulse Sensor
sampleCounter += 2; // keep track of the time in mS with this variable
int N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime; // monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise
// find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
 
if(Signal < thresh && N > (IBI/5)*3) // avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI
{
if (Signal < T) // T is the trough
{
T = Signal; // keep track of lowest point in pulse wave
}
}
if(Signal > thresh && Signal > P)
{ // thresh condition helps avoid noise
P = Signal; // P is the peak
} // keep track of highest point in pulse wave
// NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
// signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
if (N > 250)
{ // avoid high frequency noise
if ( (Signal > thresh) && (Pulse == false) && (N > (IBI/5)*3) )
{
Pulse = true; // set the Pulse flag when we think there is a pulse
digitalWrite(blinkPin,HIGH); // turn on pin 13 LED
IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime; // measure time between beats in mS
lastBeatTime = sampleCounter; // keep track of time for next pulse
 
if(secondBeat)
{ // if this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE
secondBeat = false; // clear secondBeat flag
for(int i=0; i<=9; i++) // seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup
{
rate[i] = IBI;
}
}
if(firstBeat) // if it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE
{
firstBeat = false; // clear firstBeat flag
secondBeat = true; // set the second beat flag
sei(); // enable interrupts again
return; // IBI value is unreliable so discard it
}
// keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values
word runningTotal = 0; // clear the runningTotal variable
for(int i=0; i<=8; i++)
{ // shift data in the rate array
rate[i] = rate[i+1]; // and drop the oldest IBI value
runningTotal += rate[i]; // add up the 9 oldest IBI values
}
rate[9] = IBI; // add the latest IBI to the rate array
runningTotal += rate[9]; // add the latest IBI to runningTotal
runningTotal /= 10; // average the last 10 IBI values
BPM = 60000/runningTotal; // how many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
QS = true; // set Quantified Self flag
// QS FLAG IS NOT CLEARED INSIDE THIS ISR
pulse = BPM;
}
}
if (Signal < thresh && Pulse == true)
{ // when the values are going down, the beat is over
digitalWrite(blinkPin,LOW); // turn off pin 13 LED
Pulse = false; // reset the Pulse flag so we can do it again
amp = P - T; // get amplitude of the pulse wave
thresh = amp/2 + T; // set thresh at 50% of the amplitude
P = thresh; // reset these for next time
T = thresh;
}
if (N > 2500)
{ // if 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
thresh = 512; // set thresh default
P = 512; // set P default
T = 512; // set T default
lastBeatTime = sampleCounter; // bring the lastBeatTime up to date
firstBeat = true; // set these to avoid noise
secondBeat = false; // when we get the heartbeat back
}
sei(); // enable interrupts when youre done!
}// end isr
void esp_8266()
{
// TCP connection AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","184.106.153.149",80
String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"";
cmd += "184.106.153.149"; // api.thingspeak.com
cmd += "\",80";
ser.println(cmd);
Serial.println(cmd);
if (ser.find("Error")){
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART error");
  return;
}
String getStr = "GET /update?api_key=";
getStr += apiKey;
getStr +="&field1=";
getStr +=String(pulse);
getStr +="&field2=";
getStr +=String(temp);
getStr += "\r\n\r\n";
// send data length
cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=4,";
cmd += String(getStr.length());
ser.println(cmd);
Serial.println(cmd);
delay(1000);
ser.print(getStr);
Serial.println(getStr); //thingspeak needs 15 sec delay between updates
delay(3000);
}
void read_temp()
{
int temp_val = analogRead(A1);
float mv = (temp_val/1024.0)*5000;
float cel = mv/10;
temp = (cel*9)/5 + 32;
Serial.print("Temperature:");
Serial.println(temp);
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("BPM :");
lcd.setCursor(7,0);
lcd.print(BPM);
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("Temp.:");
lcd.setCursor(7,1);
lcd.print(temp);
lcd.setCursor(13,1);
lcd.print("F");
}
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\vaadh\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\testing_LED_blinking\testing_LED_blinking.ino: In function 'void esp_8266()':
C:\Users\vaadh\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\testing_LED_blinking\testing_LED_blinking.ino:282:21: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
 if (ser.find("Error")){
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem of the Arduino core Stream class's `find` method. The type of the parameter should be `const char*` but it is `char*`.

Cast the parameter to `char*` to indicate to the compiler that it is OK.

```
ser.find((char*) "Error")
```